# Does Blender have an asset library plugin?

Tags: file-browser

Is there an addon or plugin to have a visual asset library to drag and drop onto the 3D view area other than the file open/browsing dialog?

Comment: Actually there are quite a few, a free one is https://github.com/BlenderAid/Asset-Flinger

Answer (score 1):

This one seems very great : https://blendermarket.com/products/asset-management/ (I haven't try it yet).